# How do I terminate a long running SQL query in shell script using SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT

Tags: shell, db2, db2-luw

How do I terminate a long running SQL query in shell script using `SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT`?

Answer (score 0):

Query timeout for ODBC/CLI applications, including the DB2 CLP (which I assume you mean by "shell script"), can be set using the [`QueryTimeout` parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/r0057060.html) in `db2dsdriver.cfg`.

You can read more about that configuration file [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/c0054555.html).

Comment: can you please share any example . I am not able to figure out where do I need to write this piece of code

Answer (score -1):

You can use the wait for feature before terminating the sql query by setting the value to be waited for.

```
SQLSetStmtAttr( command, SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)timeOut, NULL );
```

Comment: How can I use SQLSetStmtAttr directly in a shell script file .  Currently my script is like                                                                                       db2 "export to $data of del modified by coldel| datesiso nochardel messages $DOM_LOG/$LOGFILE  

select * from orders where CREATED_DTTM > '2014-01-01'
"